# CGRect gets corrupted when passed up the stack

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, return-value, cgrect, nsinvocation

I have these 4 lines of code inside a function

```
void * someFunction() {
        ... code to create invocation and other things
        CGRect aRect;
        [invocation getReturnValue:&aRect];
        finalValue = &aRect;
        return finalValue
}
```

Basically, I get the return value from an `NSInvocation` and put the returned value at the memory address of aRect (that, AFAIK, should be on the stack). The return value is obviously a CGRect.
someFunction() returns a pointer to "anything". The returned value can be a pointer to int, a pointer to float, or a pointer to an object.
All the mentioned types returns correctly, but I have a problem with CGRect.

Debugging, aRect is set correctly after `getReturnValue:`:

```
0x07127550 {{0, 20}, {320, 460}}
```

The problem is when I return (the code is the same as the other types, int, long, or object)

```
// the returned value is a generic pointer
void * returnValue = someFunction(arguments);
// cast this generic pointer to a CGRect pointer.
CGRect returnedRect = *(CGRect *)returnValue;
```

the result should go into returnedRect, but debugging again, the CGRect has corrupted values:

```
0x07127570 {{-1.99891, 2.61428e-38}, {-1.99891, 2.90066e-38}}
```

As you can see, the memory address is the same, so the rect seems to have been corrupted.

If I change the first function like this:

```
        CGRect *aRect = malloc(sizeOfReturnValue);
        [invocation getReturnValue:aRect];
        finalValue = aRect;
        return finalValue;
```

the rect is passed correctly without corruption.
This happens because, in this case, I've allocated the struct on the heap

```
0x08070580 {{0, 20}, {320, 460}}
```

But why it doesn't work setting it on the stack?
The same exact code works correctly for int, float, long, and double.
What am I missing?

Last note: I'm using ARC

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
void * someFunction() {
        ... code to create invocation and other things
        CGRect aRect;
        [invocation getReturnValue:&aRect];
        finalValue = &aRect;
        return finalValue
}
```

You're returning an address of a temporary object and invoking undefined behavior. `aRect` is invalid as soon as `someFunction` returns.

When you access it the memory address in `CGRect returnedRect = *(CGRect *)returnValue;` you're using memory that doesn't belong to you hence why you're seeing weird numbers.

If you want to return the CGRect, you could just return the object directly. For example

```
CGRect someFunction() {
        ... code to create invocation and other things
        CGRect aRect;
        [invocation getReturnValue:&aRect];
        return aRect;
}
```

and use it like

```
CGRect returnedRect = someFunction(arguments);
```

Comment: WTF...you are right! I'm passing up only a pointer, so this can't be a pointer to a stack value, because when the function that created it ends, the value becomes garbage. I can't change the function to return a CGRect because I need it to return a void*, but I can allocate the value on the heap with malloc. For this reason, even if it was working (I was lucky), there is a problem even with int, long, double, so I have to modify that code too. Thanks